# Query executed without errors but no data in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

After executing the SQL file below to create the appropriate tables(which gets executed correctly without errors),

```
<?php
 try {
        require_once 'dbcon.php';

        $sql_file = 'mysql.sql';

        $contents = file_get_contents($sql_file);

      $comment_patterns = array('/\/\*.*(\n)*.*(\*\/)?/', 
                            '/\s*--.*\n/', 
                            '/\s*#.*\n/', 
                          );

      $contents = preg_replace($comment_patterns, "\n", $contents);

      $statements = explode(";\n", $contents);
      $statements = preg_replace("/\s/", ' ', $statements);

      foreach ($statements as $query) {

        if(trim($query) != '') {
         $db->query($query);

          if ($db->errno) {

            throw new Exception("Fail to load data in database (".$db->errno.")");

          }
        }
      }
```

Running the following query right after the `foreach` gets executed successfully without errors and success message gets printed. However , no data gets inserted into the database.

```
      $cql = "INSERT INTO config (logo,brand,provider,mail_type,url) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
      $cstmt = $db->prepare($cql);
      $sch_logo = 'logo.png';
      $sch_brand = 'brand.png';
      $provider = 'other';
      $mail_type = 'mail';
      $cstmt->bind_param('sssss',$sch_logo,$sch_brand,$provider,$mail_type,$site_url);
      $cstmt->execute();

     if($cstmt->affected_rows === 1){
      echo 'Identity verified. Thank you';
      }
     else{
      throw new Exception("An error occurred Performing this operation.");
}
}
 catch(Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo ' <div class="text-warning">
    <b>'.$e->getMessage().'</b> </div>';
    exit(); 
  }
?>
```

I have printed out `$cstmt->error` and `$cstmt->errno` and they all return `0` . which seems fine but don't why the data doesn't get inserted into the fields. Anything am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score -4):

```
Try this:

$cql = "INSERT INTO config (logo,brand,provider,mail_type,url) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
      $cstmt = $db->prepare($cql);
      $sch_logo = 'logo.png';
      $sch_brand = 'brand.png';
      $provider = 'other';
      $mail_type = 'mail';
      $cstmt->bind_param('sssss',$sch_logo,$sch_brand,$provider,$mail_type,$site_url);

     **if($cstmt->execute()){**
      echo 'Identity verified. Thank you';
      }
     else{
      throw new Exception("An error occurred Performing this operation.");
}
}
 catch(Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo ' <div class="text-warning">
    <b>'.$e->getMessage().'</b> </div>';
    exit(); 
  }
```

Comment: What is this that I should try exactly??